# Usage of the word "probably"

Tags: word-usage, will-would, can-may

Consider the following sentences:

> She will probably come to the party.
>
> He may probably forget his umbrella.

In the second sentence, isn't the word **probably** redundant? The uncertainty is already stated by the use of **may**. In the first sentence, it's almost an oxymoron!

Why is **probably** used in cases like these? Or am I wrong thinking these usages exist? (I'm not from an English speaking land)

Comment: I think this is subject to interpretation, but I think the sentence "He may forget his umbrella" admits to the potential for forgetting, but I don't how probable it is.  In other words it might be 1 in a million or it might be 50/50.  But if I add *probably* that moves things into the 50/50 or higher range.

Comment: It's called a double modal, like _She may have to go, after all_, which represents a possibility (epistemic _may_) of a necessity (deontic _have to_). Double modals are common in language, and show up repeatedly in various English dialects, even with modal auxiliary verbs: _might could, shouldn't oughta,_ etc. [Modality is famously irregular and idiomatic](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Modality.pdf); modals overlap in form, usage, and meaning in unpredictable ways. Redundancy is the least of the problems; indeed, redundancy is a modal feature, not a bug.

Comment: @Jim Thanks for the explanation. :) I think you can convert it to an answer. (and I can delete this comment :P)

Comment: @JohnLawler That was well explained. :) The link you referenced was good too. But I'm afraid the points in there are too complex for me. Anyway please convert it as an answer so that I can accept it as the correct one, if it turns out to be.

Comment: Don't worry, it's just as good there as in an answer. Answers are just as likely to disappear as comments, and nobody searches anyway, so the difference doesn't matter.

Comment: Does anyone *really* use "may probably" like that? I think given OP is a non-native speaker, probably the only sensible answer is *This is not normal English*.

Comment: Yes, and *He may perhaps forget his umbrella* is even more redundant (and sounds better, too).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In written [English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=may%20probably%2C%20will%20probably&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmay%20probably%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwill%20probably%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmay%20probably%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwill%20probably%3B%2Cc1), the phrase *will probably* is 87 times **more** likely to appear than *may probably*, including the month of *May*, and a preponderance of references from the 19th and early 20th centuries. The construction *may probably* is certainly acceptable grammatically and it doesn't even sound **terribly** awkward, but it is not at all common.

Generally, the modal *may* expresses four ideas, but only two of them comfortably apply to *He may probably forget his umbrella*. I offer the options from most comfortable to least:

> 1.0 Expressing **possibility**:
>
> *that may be true*

Since possibility and probability are logically intertwined, one might consider it a redundancy, but it could also be a matter of emphasis or even a subtle distinction between the possibility of may and the probability of probably.

*He will probably forget his umbrella*, gets the job done colloquially.

*He may **perhaps** forget his umbrella*, is even better, creating a similar redundant emphasis.

*He may probably forget his umbrella*, might capture a level of attention by its uniqueness.

> 1.1 Used when admitting that something is so before making another, more important point:
>
> *they may have been old-fashioned, but they were excellent teachers*

Hypothetically, the next sentence in the larger context might be: *He will certainly remember his wallet*. If that were the case, *may* in the first sentence would draw a comparison in parallel with *will* in the second sentence. The words *probably* and *certainly* would then emphasize the likelihood of each possibility: *He may probably forget his umbrella. He will certainly remember his wallet*.

The other two common meanings of *may* would almost universally demand a different syntax:

> 2.0 Expressing permission:
>
> *you may use a sling if you wish*

For *permission*, theoretically, one might say, *He probably may forget his umbrella*, but it is hard to imagine giving someone permission to forget. It is even harder to imagine a situation where offering a person permission to forget his umbrella is a matter of probability, unless it were somehow tied irrationally to the probability of the weather.

> 3.0 Expressing a wish or hope:
>
> *may she rest in peace*

*May he probably forget his umbrella*, seems like a strange wish. I would go for the whole nine yards and say, *May he forget his umbrella!*

Comment: No mench (i.e., don't mention it!). Don